# Incorrect result when making a calculator

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, selection, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator in my class for using VB2010 and I am building a function procedure that is does the math part of it. I use a `Select Case` statement with a char and all I get when doing the math `7 + 7` is 0 which is not right. I didn't know where to fix. I'm using arrays that are dimmed in the front and I have both calling on the function and the actual function. Does it have to do with my arrays that I'm getting bad data?

```
Private Sub EqualsButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EqualsButton.Click
    If CalculatorRichTextBox.Text <> Nothing Then
        NumberArray(CountNumber) = Double.Parse(CalculatorRichTextBox.Text)
        NumberArray(CountNumber + 1) = DoMathProcedure(NumberArray(CountNumber - 1), MathArray(CountMath), NumberArray(CountNumber))
        CountNumber += 1
        CalculatorRichTextBox.Text = NumberArray(CountNumber).ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Function DoMathProcedure(ByVal MathNumber1 As Double, ByVal MathSymbol As Char, ByVal MathNumber2 As Double) As Double
    Dim Answer As Double
    Select Case MathSymbol
        Case "+"
            Answer = MathNumber1 + MathNumber2
        Case "-"
            Answer = MathNumber1 - MathNumber2
        Case "X"
            Answer = MathNumber1 * MathNumber2
        Case "/"
            Answer = MathNumber1 / MathNumber2
    End Select
    Return Answer

End Function




Private Sub PlusButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlusButton.Click
    'add try for not just decimal

    If CalculatorRichTextBox.Text <> Nothing Then
        NumberArray(CountNumber) = Double.Parse(CalculatorRichTextBox.Text)
        CalculatorRichTextBox.Clear()
        MathArray(CountMath) = "+"
        CountMath += 1
        CountNumber += 1
    Else
        CalculatorRichTextBox.Text = "ERROR"
        ErrorBoolan = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you debug it what is the operator that is being used in DoMathProcedure?  I suspect the operator isn't set to anything so DoMathProcedure doesn't enter any Case.

Comment: In particular, `Case Else: MsgBox("Unexpected operator '" & MathSymbol & "' encountered!")` would help a good bit.

Comment: In the function call the second argument is MathArray(CountMath). When is this set?

Comment: i added more to what i already have and this is the code i have for the + button but it is similar to all the other */- buttons. wondering if the char is going to my array.

Comment: i think the numbers are not setting when running it all i get is a 0 on any function but when i debug i cant frind what values are set where. im still new to this.